# Zend Framework 2 need PHP version 5.3.3?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

They declare PHP_VERSION>=5.3.3, however, in its code, something like 'trait' which was introduced in 5.4 appear everywhere.I'm confused!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't **use** traits, it **lets you use** traits. The requirement is 5.3.3, but using the traits part of the framework requires 5.4.

It doesn't break anything.

*Update*:
See also [this recent issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-537).

Answer (score 2):

ZF2 has some traits and other PHP 5.4 features but are only enabled if you use PHP 5.4 else the same equivalent for PHP 5.3 is used